# How to get file path to a resource inside a jar

Tags: java, deployment, apache-spark-sql, resources, executable-jar

I am trying to load a file which is in src/main/resources. It works fine in my local but when I deploy a jar , seeing an issue . I know how to get the Inputstream but in my case I need to load file.

**File location:**

```
src
   main
      resources
            cert
               truststore.ks
```

String filename = cert/truststore.ks

```
spark.sparkContext().addFile(getAbsolutePath(filename));
```

Method:

```
public String getAbsolutePath(String fileName) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    return getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).toExternalForm();
  }
```

Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper$.main(DriverWrapper.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper.main(DriverWrapper.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: jar:file:/work/run/driver-20200525203940-0037/service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/cert/truststore.ks
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:171)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:1519)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:1499)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: jar:file:/work/run/driver-20200525203940-0037/service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/cert/truststore.ks
    at java.net.URI.checkPath(URI.java:1823)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:745)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:202)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using -

```
SparkFiles.get(fileName)
```

Here is the [source-git](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/df2a1fe131476aac128d63df9b06ec4bca0c2c07/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkFiles.scala#L30)

For Example follow this [gist](https://gist.github.com/skale1990/26448400c7655543f9e1177dd17763bf#file-problemsolvertest-scala-L364)